# I'm wondering why using cp in this way takes over 4 seconds

Tags: performance, cp

```
time cp /usr/local/bin/* /media/username/flash-drive-label

real    0m4.142s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Normally using cp with wildcard (even when there are hundreds of files) like that never takes more than a second. The directory contents I backed up here only contained 33 files, all less than a megabyte. Why would this command take a whopping 4 seconds to carry out? It doesn't have anything to do with the "time" command, because i noticed this the first time i ran cp in the exact same way.

Comment: Would the filesystem you are copying to be of the FAT family ?

Comment: Is this limited to a single USB device? How about a certain USB port?

Comment: @MC68020 yeah it's vfat

Comment: The copy probably takes 30-40 seconds (if not longer) but the caching subsystem works correctly to make it _feel like_ it's much faster. Don't pull the flash drive until you've either unmounted it or at least run `sync`

Comment: @MC68020, it doesn't really answer it but it's something interesting for me to read and speculate about. I am convinced that it has something to do with the flashdrive and not the desktop at this point.

Comment: is the USB drive mounted with the `sync`, `dirsync`, or `flush` option?  check the mount options with `mount | grep /media/username/flash-drive-label`

Answer (score 1):

I am only guessing at a possibility with this;

But I wonder if there is some limitation on the bus or device you are copying to, that may be affecting your I/O performance?

Along with the `time` command, I would run it with `cp -v` (verbose) option to see if it stalls momentarily on a particular file.

Comment: I think you're on to something, each file transfer basically took the exact same amount of time with the verbose option.